# Web components with common dependencies

Tags: reactjs, web-component

I have a number of web components consumed in a separate application. They all depend on React. React is not in the parent App, but all of the components will depend on React. Is it expensive to call and load React in each component, even over CDN? Or is there a better way to specify a common dependency shared by multiple web components?

Comment: Look into webpack or browserify to bundle files and manage dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm already using webpack. Each component is an individual entry point with React defined as an external - so that React is not bundled in each component's bundle.js. The question is, if i call <script src="react.js"> within multiple html imports, does React get downloaded/executed multiple times. The answer i've found so far is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser will keep React in cache so even if you call it several times it will be downloaded once. You can see it in Chrome Dev Tools (HTTP code `304 Not Modified`). So it shouldn't impact overall performances.

If you use the Web Component technology you could leverage **HTML Imports** to load dependancies.

You could also use a module loader like **RequireJs**.